# "24 years old or 24 year old"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, rules

I'm wondering if there should be an "s" when telling about ages. I have heard from my native English friend says "I'm 24 year old" is it correct?

Comment: This is general reference, and as such I would advise the user to do some minimal research (there are hundreds of English grammar websites) beforehand. If they are still unclear, post a question explaining their difficulty on EL&U's sister site: English Language Learners. As it stands now, this question is even too basic for ELL standards http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question had already an answer on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/a-six-year-old-boy-or-a-six-years-old-boy).

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you, but if you think that this question is too basic, just ignore it, as simple as that. I have already got the answer from other users anyway, so you don't need to bother.

Comment: Actually, the exact phrase you quoted in your question **I'm 24 year old** is incorrect, nobody has picked up on that. Regardless, the answer you have awarded is clear and correct.

Comment: That's why it's confusing me as I've heard it from my English native friend, so I posted it here hoping to get a clear answer and explanation. I'm glad that I've found this site thinking that it could help me to improve my English without judging. I think I made a mistake. Some users are giving non-sense comments instead of giving their answers.

Comment: Perhaps you misheard your friend, or maybe it was a slip of the tongue. In speech these things happen. If you need to write your age then it's: *I'm 24 years old*; *I'm (or I am)* **a** *24-year-old girl/student/graduate*; and the most informal way to express age is: "I'm 24".

Comment: It is quite possible that an English person would say "I'm 24 year old" but it is _bad usage_. The same kind of person might say "I've got 5 pound." without an 's'. It is illiterate. You should avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When describing someone by their age, you would drop the 's'. This is because when you express a unit of measurement (in this case time, or age) as an adjective, it become singular.

> - The 20-year-old student you're referring to was last seen in the park.
> - I am a 24-year-old college graduate.

However, when someone is stating their age, you would attach an 's'. 
This occurs because when a unit of measurement is used as a noun, it becomes plural.

> - He is 32 years old.
> - I am 40 years old.

I think anyway, hope this helps some. :)

Comment: "when describing someone by their age" is rather a vague expression. Such adjectives are compound adjectives. When in such adjectives there is a cardinal number + noun the noun has no plural s.